# Displaying base64 encoded image in GWT CellTable ImageCell

Tags: java, image, gwt

I'm trying to display a base 64 encoded image in my cell table. I've tried using the ImageCell but nothing is displayed.

```
Column<DTO, String> ownerImageColumn = new Column<DTO, String>(new ImageCell())
{
   @Override
   public String getValue(DTO object)
   {
      return object.getOwner().getPicture();
   }
};
```

Has anyone done something similar? The user can upload their own image so I need it to be dynamic and not use ImageResourceCell. I can see the image if I do:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.setUrl(dto.getOwner().getPicture());
```

Is this possible some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not an easy one. You have to write your own Cell and Column class:

```
public class Base64ImageCellTest implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        CellTable<String> cellTable = new CellTable<String>();

        Column<String, String> imageColumn = new ImageColumn();
        cellTable.addColumn(imageColumn, "Images");

        ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable);

        List<String> list = dataProvider.getList();
        list.add("data:image/png;base64,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");
        list.add("data:image/png;base64,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%3D%3D");
        list.add("data:image/png;base64,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");

        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(cellTable);
    }

    private static class Base64ImageCell extends AbstractCell<String> {

        @Override
        public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            if (value != null) {
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<img src=\"" + value +"\" />");
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ImageColumn extends Column<String, String> {

        public ImageColumn() {
            super(new Base64ImageCell());
        }

        @Override
        public String getValue(String base64Data) {
            return base64Data;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've played around with my custom cell but didn't think of making my own column. I've modified the code to use my DTO but it seems I need to make my own column for every type of Cell Table where I use different DTO's unless it's possible to solve using generics. Not a big issue though.